# Задать пользователя в пуле php-fpm

Tags: php, php-fpm, redhat

Подключаюсь по ssh к серверу. Я становлюсь пользователем EFB\production. При создании файлов они создаются с группой EFB\domain^users.
В пуле я хочу настроить свойства user и group от текущего пользователя, но при попытке перезагрузить fpm я получаю сообщение об ошибке:
 Starting php-fpm [27-Jun-2018 22:13:41] ERROR: [pool www] please specify user and group other than root

Comment: Там все элементарно в www.conf. Просто укажите user и group

Comment: какого юзера и какую группу? Я же говорю что если указываю текущего то ошибку выкидывает, а если указать nginx, то все ок, но тогда каждый раз chown директории придется делать

Comment: Что значит - текущего? Кто это такой - текущий? Нет такого термина в Linux. А ставить надо nginx, да. Ну или ещё куча вариантов, с 775 и 664, и юзером в группе nginx. Смотря сколько сайтов на сервере, нужно ли их разграничивать, что там с sftp и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема решилась оборачиванием имени пользователя в кавычки. Видимо backslash использовать нельзя в конфиге в значении параметров.